# QtCreator says: x "SDK tools are not installed"

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtandroidextras

I open Extras-->Settings in QtCreator and the error "SDK tools are not installed" is shown on the page 'Devices'. What exactly is missing?

I installed Android Studio 3.5.3 in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio. And Qt Creator 4.11.0 (Community) is installed in D:\Qt\Qt5.12.7\Tools\QtCreator\bin.

I looked at File-->Settings in Android Studio but there is everything installed in "Appearance&Behavior"-->"System Settings"-->"Android SDK"-->"SDK Tools".

My OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out, I must set "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" instead of "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio" in the lineedit field "Android-SDK" on page "Devices"-->"Android" in Qt Creator's settings dialog.
Now it says "Android settings are correct. (SDK-Version: 26.1.1, NDK-Version: 18.1.5063045)"